# Get the node indexes of connected components in a graph (matlab)

Tags: matlab, graph, connected-components

I have two Adjacency Matrix (same size), and I want to check how many nodes in a given connected components of the two graphs are same.

For example, if A has three connected components of size 4,5 and 6 and B has two connected components of size 3 and 7.  Suppose I want to compare the number of nodes shared in all connected components greater than 5 i.e.  I want to get the number of nodes common to the connected components of size (5,6) in A and connected component of size 7 in B, and the number of nodes not in connected components of size (5,6) in A but in connected component of size 7 in B and the number of nodes in connected components of size (5,6) in A but not in connected component of size 7 in B.

So far I did this,

```
Abins = conncomp(graph(A));
Bbins = conncomp(graph(B));
[Ca, iaa, ica] = unique(Abins);
[Cb, iab, icb] = unique(Bbins);
Cb_counts = accumarray(icb,1);
```

Now, I am not sure how can I get the indices of the nodes such that Cb_counts > 5

Comment: I don't have MATLAB to try it out, but `conncomp` does have another option output `binsizes` that gives you the size of each connected component it finds. Is that what you're looking for?